# Pass setState as a callback to another setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Is it the right way to call setState as a callback in another one? Here a piece of my code.

This is my initial state:

```
state = {
    resumeCollection: [],
    filters: {
        educationLevels: [],
        educationFields: [],
        jobAdvertisementId: []
    }
};
```

And this a componentDidMount section:

```
componentDidMount() {



    this.setState(prevState =>( {filters : {
        jobAdvertisementId :    [...prevState.filters.jobAdvertisementId, {value: this.props.router.query.value, id: this.props.router.query.id}]}

    } 
    )
    , () => this.setState(state => { 

        return({

            resumeCollection : state.resumeCollection.filter(resume => resume.jobAdvertisementId == state.filters.jobAdvertisementId[0].id )
        });
         }
    )

    )
}
```

Comment: `setState` calls are batched, so its better you combine if there are things to be in done in `setState`

Comment: @tarzenchugh I need to set 'jobAdvertisementId' then set 'resumeCollection' by 'jobAdvertisementId' value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice against doing 2 state updates like that as it will introduce a useless second render.

If you need to set portion of the state based on another portion of the state, you can calculate it and store it outside the return statement inside a variable and used it where you need it.

In your case it might look something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const nextJobAdvertisementId = [
      ...prevState.filters.jobAdvertisementId,
      {
        value: this.props.router.query.value,
        id: this.props.router.query.id
      }
    ];
    return {
      filters: {
        jobAdvertisementId: nextJobAdvertisementId
      },
      resumeCollection: prevState.resumeCollection.filter(
        resume => resume.jobAdvertisementId === nextJobAdvertisementId[0].id
      )
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add another setState as a part of callback to the first setState(), when you want to set another state based on first.

In the below example I set 'b' state based on state 'a':

e.g

```
const setB = () => {
  if(this.state.a)
    this.setState({b:"Success"})
  else
    this.setState({b:"failure"})
}

this.setState({a:true},this.setB)
```